# How to limit the timeout when running DOMDocument->loadHtmlFile?

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to get the content from some website but if the website is down, it takes a really long time to open (like 1 min).

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://somewebsite.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$links = $xpath->query("//p[@class='result']");
```

How can I make it timeout after 5 seconds?

Comment: You basically want to check if a website is online... Check this one out: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-website-is-available/

Comment: Wow this s really helped ^^ thank bestprogrammerintheworld

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to time the code and to timeout if the remote call takes too long

the following id the link where you can some code too

[Link to curl code](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/Q_26980898.html)